Suggested Edit review: no action available
I just found this edit suggestion which doesn't allow me to do anything else than skipping it:

Looking at the profile of the user who suggested the edit didn't give me any extra information about what happened:

To me, it looks like the post was deleted, but previously when I encountered an edit suggestion to a deleted post, I was still able to review it. Can somebody explain to me what's different here?
I skipped and was told that I have reached the daily maximum reviews, apparently the limit was reduced from 40 to 20 while I wrote this meta post. This still doesn't explain why there is no post link shown for the edit suggestion in the second screenshot.

I think this is related to some testing / experimenting (deleted answer, link for 10k+, image of the same) cocomac did for discussions.

Interestingly, I see all the usual actions.  But mods often observe different behaviors than non-mods.

Firefox kind of messed up the screenshot in my previous comment, this one doesn't have the header in between the image.

I'm on mobile and also cannot see any review actions from the dropdown.

Interesting, also ran into this suggested edit naturally in the queue. Might just need to have a mod accept/reject it so it doesn't keep popping up?

I just went ahead and cleared the suggested edit so it stops appearing for people.

Yep, I did this.
Here's the interesting part of the deleted post linked in the comments.

With a caveat of please don't try this at home, I managed to do this:

[...] This has some unfortunate side-effects (hence the you really shouldn't try to do this yourself) that aren't obvious, but there are some hidden "features" that produce strange results.

As Thom A observed here, some folks were experimenting with Discussions, myself included. I was curious what happens if a logged-in user (under 2k) submits a suggested Discussions edit, and this was the result.
Aside from just digging through the queue, the edit isn't even linked from the list of my Suggestions (until it got rejected), which made it hard to find. Interestingly, I think the post link was present, but you had to use the browser dev tools to find it.
